# Older versions of @types is causing problems

Tags: typescript, npm, types, typescript-typings

For some time now i have experienced that my React project is suddenly failing to build

The problem comes if i delete the node_modules folder and the lock file. After running npm install, i run a npm build, and then it cant compile.

For example i get this error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3782:13
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'dialog' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DialogHTMLAttributes<HTMLDialogElement>, HTMLDialogElement>'.
```

I am using @types/react": "16.0.36 in my package.json under devDependencies. Updating to @types/react": "16.0.38 solved the problem this time.

What i dont understand is, why is this package suddenly causing problems when it worked "yesterday". And this is just one of many packages (@types) that suddenly causes my application not being able to build.

In my tsconfig.json i have even added node_modules as excluded, but this seems to have no impact.

Can anyone explain why this happens to me all the time?